# Disable client extension if server does not accept extensions

Tags: websocket, netty

I have a WebSocket client that uses the netty `WebSocketClientCompressionHandler` to support compression extension. For this extension to work properly I need to set the `allowExtensions` value to true when creating a `newHandshaker` using the `WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory`.

At times when the server does not support these extensions it responds without a `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions`. If that is the case if reserved (RSV) bits are used, the client should terminate the connection immediately.

Since I am creating the `WebSocketClientHandshaker` before I could get any response from the server I am unable to set the value of `allowExtensions` to false afterwards when I come to know that the server does not support extensions.

Is it in anyway possible to set the value of `allowExtensions` to false after I receive the response from server (or inform netty) so that netty will close the connection if RSV bit is set due to protocol violation?

(For the server implementation I do check the client request headers for `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` before creating the handshaker which is fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I had was to replace the `WebSocketFrameDecoder` after finishing the handshake and set the `allowExtensions` value to false if the handshake response does not have the extension header:

```
handshaker.finishHandshake(ctx.channel(), handshakeResponse);
            Channel channel = ctx.channel();
            String extensionsHeader = handshakeResponse.headers().getAsString(HttpHeaderNames.SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSIONS);
            if (extensionsHeader == null) {
                // This replaces the frame decoder to make sure the rsv bits are not allowed
                channel.pipeline().replace(WebSocketFrameDecoder.class, "ws-decoder",
                                           new WebSocket13FrameDecoder(false, false, handshaker.maxFramePayloadLength(),
                                                                       false));
            }
```